# Why does Localytics require google-play-services:ads?

Tags: android, google-play-services, localytics

I was running into problems with how many methods I have in my project, and have finally fixed it.

However, I noticed that the [Localytics documentation](https://docs.localytics.com/dev/android.html#getting-started-android) says to include the dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads`. It is never used anywhere in my project, and I can't find anything on their website as to why its a required dependency.

My app runs perfectly fine without it as far as I can tell, but I have only tried building the project as a debug build.

Answer (score 4):

`play-services-ads` used to be the only way of gaining access to the [Advertising ID](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248) and it seems that functionality was added back in version 2.60 as per the [SDK Changelog](https://docs.localytics.com/dev/sdk-changelog.html#developers-sdk-changelog-android). The only mention of it appears to be in the [testing attribution section](https://docs.localytics.com/dev/android.html#testing-attribution), although that doesn't mean it is only used for attribution.

As of Google Play services 9.0, it has been moved to the `play-services-basement` dependency, which is much smaller. You should be able to use that dependency in place of `play-services-ads` without issue.

Comment: And I'd strongly recommend filing a bug/writing to their community forum to inform them of the smaller dependency so they can update their docs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how I can check if using `play-services-basement` is a solution. It seems like it is a proper solution though, so once I confirm it I will accept your answer.